# Sum of 3 vectors is $\vec 0$

Tags: vectors

So i have this problem:  $|\vec{a}| = 5$, $|\vec{b}| = 6$,$|\vec{c}| = 7$ and $\vec{a}$+$\vec{b}$+$\vec{c}$=0. Calculate the sum $\vec{a}$·$\vec{b}$+$\vec{b}$·$\vec{c}$+$\vec{c}$·$\vec{a}$.

I have no clue how to go about this, any help would be appreciated (hopefully the problem makes sense, i'm translating things directly, so if something isn't adding up (hehe), please do let me know, thanks.

Comment: how are they unit if their respective lengths are $5$, $6$, and $7$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Where did the title come from?

Comment: Such a cute little question! Is there a suitable tag? I would label it "puzzle", but the tag's description made me wonder if there is a better one.

Comment: Without fancy ideas, you know $c=-a-b$ and you know $\lvert c\rvert$, therefore you know $a\cdot b$. Then the requested quantity is a polynomial in $a\cdot b$, $\lvert a\rvert$ and $\lvert b\rvert$.

Comment: @paperskilltrees This is not a puzzle. It is a straight forward vector algebra problem.

Comment: @JohnDouma You can solve this problem using a straightforward computation, or you can make use of a nice algebraic observation made in [emacs...'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4469913/774351). I believe that another commenter implicitly referred to it as a "fancy idea". I find this a characteristic of many puzzles. Probably we understand and use the word "puzzle" in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: square $\vec a+ \vec b+ \vec c$

> $0=(\vec a+\vec b+\vec c)^2 = \vec a^2+\vec b^2+\vec c^2+2(\vec a \cdot \vec b+\vec b \cdot \vec c+\vec a \cdot \vec c) \;\;\;\; \\ = 5^2+6^2+7^2 + 2(\vec a \cdot \vec b+\vec b \cdot \vec c+\vec a \cdot \vec c) $

Answer (score 2):

@emacs-drives-me-nuts' solution is the correct one. Here's a fun, incorrect solution:

From $a + b + c = 0$, we have $a + b = -c$, $a + c = -b$, $b + c = -a$

Whence (the dot product commutes),

$$
\color{red}{ab + ac + bc} =\\
ab + c \cdot (a + b) =\\
ac + b \cdot (a + c) =\\
bc + a \cdot (b + c) =\\
\color{green}{ab - 49} =\\
\color{blue}{ac - 36} =\\
\color{orange}{bc - 25}
$$

Using this,
$$
\color{red}{ab + ac + bc} = ab + ab - 13 + ab - 24 = \color{green}{3ab - 37}\\
\color{red}{ab + ac + bc} = ac + 13 + ac + ac - 11 = \color{blue}{3ac + 2}\\
\color{red}{ab + ac + bc} = bc + 24 + bc + 11 + bc = \color{orange}{3bc + 35}
$$

Whence, finally, putting both of these together,
$$
\color{green}{2ab = -12}\\
\color{blue}{2ac = -38}\\
\color{orange}{2bc = -60}
$$
and
$$
\color{red}{ab + ac + bc} = - \dfrac{\color{green}{12} + \color{blue}{38} + \color{orange}{60}} {2} = -55
$$

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, this solution does tell you more.

Comment: Why "incorrect"?

Comment: The only possibly wrong thing I can see is the notation $ab$ instead of $\vec a\cdot\vec b$.

Comment: Incorrect, because there’s a much shorter (and better) answer. The proof is otherwise correct.

Comment: And I’ll actually disagree that there’s anything wrong with writing $ab$ in place of $\vec {a} \cdot \vec{b}$. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In geometric terms, these three vectors form the lengths of a triangle with sides 5, 6, and 7.  (Their sum is zero because traveling the three sides in order gets you back to where you started.)

From the Law of Cosines, the three angles of a triangle with known sides are given by:

$$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{b^2 + c^2 - a^2}{2bc}$$
$$\cos(\beta) = \frac{a^2 + c^2 - b^2}{2ac}$$
$$\cos(\gamma) = \frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab}$$

But the dot product has the property that $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} = |\vec{x}|  |\vec{y}| \cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors.  Thus,

$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} + \vec{b} \cdot \vec{c} + \vec{c} \cdot \vec{a}$$
$$=ab \cos(\gamma) + bc \cos(\alpha) + ca\cos(\beta)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(a^2 + b^2 - c^2) + \frac{1}{2}(b^2+c^2-a^2) + \frac{1}{2}(a^2 + c^2 - b^2)$$
$$= \frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{2}$$

Comment: $\vec a\cdot\vec b=ab\cos(\pi-\gamma)=-ab\cos\gamma$